# Continuous Valued POVMs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, quantum-optics, quantum-measurements

I'm thinking about the mathematical details of continuous variable QM, namely the infinite $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ bases. Is it possible (and should we) think of these bases and their measurements $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ on these bases as a sort of POVM with a continuum number of possible outcomes?

If so, how can we reconcile this with a more standard/mathematical way of understanding the probability, i.e. as a measurable space. It seems like once we try, we run into problems. For example, the plane wave Fourier basis is not renormalizable, so why are we allowed to take that as a basis?

So one more time for good measure:

1. Can we think of $\hat{x}$ measurements or measurements of intervals of $x$ as POVM elements, and is it possible to have a countable or uncountable number of such POVM elements
2. Can you, given a set $X$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $X$ which is a measurable space, produce a probability function $\mu: \Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is a probability measure on $(X, \Sigma)$ that represents said POVM
3. Why is it fine to say that the result of an $\hat{x}$ measurement on the state $|x\rangle$ is a dirac delta which is not well defined as a function and physically not meaningful, and also in the Fourier basis, a plane wave that is not $L_2$ normalizable

Comment: Did you check e.g. the older works of Holevo?  (For sure, exact x and p eigenstates are very likely not a good basis for measurement, one would rather measure in an overcomplete basis of squeezed states which have a very low uncertainty e.g. in x direction. The "pure" x measurement can then be obtained as a limiting procedure, but it is likely unphysical for more than one reason.)

Comment: I'm no expert in this field, but I think you'll find the answer to your question in the rubric of "rigged Hilbert spaces." Experts, do you (dis)agree?